# Get X509Certificate object from p12 file in XAMARIN

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

i am trying to get **X509Certificate** object from .**p12** certificate file using c# on XAMARIN.

In my button click method i have following code.

```
List<string> s = Directory.EnumerateFiles("/sdcard", "*.p12", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            TextView txtTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            txtTextView.Text = s[0];
            X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate();

           cert.Import(s[0],"eet",X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

This code find 2 certificates, both inside **/sdcard/Download/** directory. On Windows platform i am getting private key by just installing certificates into certificate store. Then i load certificate store and load a X509Certificate object. On Android i am trying to do the same but cert. store is empty even if Android say that certificate has been sucessfully installed. So i decided to read it directly from file. I think that file is found successfully. When i try to import i am getting exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
```

What i am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You have invalid password